# symfony 2 dom crawler to loop through and get links

Tags: php, symfony, dom-events

I'm trying to pass the html so I can find the title and link.  At the moment I can get all the titles at the same time, when I really want to loop through them one by one.  Also I can't get the link, the method link(); method when I hard code an actual name of a link returns, an error

```
          Current URI must be an absolute URL ("").
```

I need something that will a foreach loop and get the title and link, code is below, please help me out

```
    $html <<<<ol>
        <li
              class="first-child ol1">
              <a href="http://link1"
               class="story">
               <span class="livestats-icon livestats-1">1:</span>  Skywatchers await solar eclipse</a>
                                </li>
                                            <li
                                              class="ol2">
                                              <a
                                                href="http://link2"
                                                class="story">
                                                <span
                                                  class="livestats-icon livestats-2">2: </span>Indians caught 'cheating' in exams</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li
                                              class="ol3">
                                              <a
                                                href="http://link3"
                                                class="story">
                                                <span
                                                  class="livestats-icon  livestats-3">3: </span>Hunting for Prince's vault</a>
                                            </li>
                                                            </ol>>>>html
  $crawler = new Crawler($html);

 $message = $crawler->filterXPath('//ol')->text();

print_r($message);



$link = $crawler->selectLink('1: Skywatchers await solar eclipse')->link();


 print_r($link);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter and select your links using css selector like :

```
$links = $crawler->filter('a')->links();
```

This will select all the a tags that you have, if you want specific ones, you need a way to select them if you don't then add a css class to the  tags that you need to select and :

```
$links = $crawler->filter('.myclass')->links());
```

It will return array of links.

## Edit :

True just tried your code, you need an URI as the error says... i thought it was failing somewhere else but it fails in the crawler construct...

```
$crawler = new Crawler($html, 'http'); //http is not a valid uri obviously but it does the trick if you dont need the uri.
```

Comment: Thanks but you probably added ) on the end by mistake should be $links = $crawler->filter('a')->links();   ?   Then this returns the same error though  'Current URI must be an absolute URL ("")'  I'd love something which does it in a similar way to simpleXml

Comment: @GAV oh yes sorry without ) , well that's weird i have already worked with the crawler recently and this worked, i can't help you with the filterXPath since i never used it , i prefer css selector tho , but what does the $crawler->filter('a') returns if you dump it?

Comment: object(Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler)[263]
  protected 'uri' => null
  private 'defaultNamespacePrefix' => string 'default' (length=7)
  private 'namespaces' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private 'baseHref' => null

Comment: i am not sure about how you instantiate your crawler, can you use $crawler = new Crawler(); $crawler->addHtmlContent("<html>your html</html>"); then try again

Comment: $html = <<<'HTML'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p class="message">Hello World!</p>
        <p>Hello Crawler!</p>
        <a href='nonoon'>nonoon</a>
    </body>
</html>
HTML;
      
$crawler = new Crawler();

$crawler->addHtmlContent($html);

$message = $crawler->filter('a')->links();

var_dump($message);

Comment: @GAV ok its 1am now i will try to replicate your code tomorrow morning and see what exactly is happening !

Comment: When you manually create your crawler, if you intend on performing any work with the 'form' or 'link' functionality you really must set the uri.  The uri is the second parameter of the constructor.  Again I refer you to the [Symfony API Documentation for the DomCrawler](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html#method___construct).

Comment: True @ShaunBramley thought the code was failing somewhere else than the construct of the crawler... i updated my answer to meet your need

Comment: If you are going to load the crawler with content, you might not be aware that it is html, so you may want to go with $crawler = new DomCrawler(null, $url); $crawler->addContent($content, $headerType);  For example within a Guzzle 5 EventListener I do the following:$crawler = new Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler(null, $e->getRequest()->getUrl());
         
        $crawler->addContent(
            $e->getResponse()->getBody()->__toString(),
            $e->getResponse()->getHeader('Content-Type')
        );

Answer (score 1):

The error you are receiving is actually an InvalidArgumentException that is being thrown from within the Symfony\DomCrawler\Link [constructor](https://github.com/symfony/DomCrawler/blob/master/Link.php#L52).  This means that the value you are providing to the [selectLink()](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html#method_selectLink) method is not a valid name as seen in the [API](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html#method_selectLink):

> Selects links by name or alt value for clickable images.

The DomCrawler does have the [links()](https://github.com/symfony/DomCrawler/blob/master/Crawler.php#L742) method which according to the [API Documentation](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html#method_links) will:

> Returns an array of Link objects for the nodes in the list.

Comment: I get this error message ' public function __construct(\DOMElement $node, $currentUri, $method = 'GET')
    {
        if (!in_array(strtolower(substr($currentUri, 0, 4)), array('http', 'file'))) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Current URI must be an absolute URL ("%s").', $currentUri));
        }
        $this->setNode($node);

Comment: The 2nd, 3rd and 5th link you provided, stopped working. FYI